# How does IntelliJ know if a directory is a 'source' or a 'test source'?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

How does IntelliJ know if a directory is a 'source' or a 'test source'? How can I  consistently mark a directory as a 'test source'?

**build.gradle 1**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('src/main/java')

        testSourceDirs += file('src/awesome-test/java')
    }
}
```

Using "build.gradle 1" file, `src/awesome-test/java` is marked as a 'test source'.

**build.gradle 2**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('src/main/java')

        testSourceDirs += file('src/awesome-test/java')
    }
}

sourceSets {
    'awesome-test' {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/awesome-test/java'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}
```

However as soon as you add a source set that references this directory ("build.gradle 2") then `src/awesome-test/java` is marked as a 'source'.

**build.gradle 3**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('src/main/java')

        testSourceDirs += file('src/awesome-test/java')
    }
}

sourceSets {
    'awesome-test' {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/awesome-test/java'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

task awesomeTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.'awesome-test'.output.classesDir
    classpath += sourceSets.'awesome-test'.runtimeClasspath
}
```

And just to confuse things beyond any hope of understanding, if I add a `Test` type task then `src/awesome-test/java` is once again marked as 'test source'.

***Notes:** IntelliJ 13.0.2, Gradle 1.9*

Comment: Here is how to do it easily: stackoverflow.com/a/36057080/715269

Comment: @Gangnus, this question was in relation to how Idea determines the source type **automatically** based on the Idea config in Gradle.

Comment: Looks like IntelliJ is adding support for custom source sets in version 2016.1

Comment: 1. you are solving the problem by Gradle. But who said it can be solved by Gradle only? 2. That your **automatically** is strange - to set roots my a click is much more easy. 3. I struggled with Gradle, too - in vain - and found that setting by click - and was happy. I thought it could help you. Alas. But surely, this way could help many people, even if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

> "How does IntelliJ know if a directory is a 'source' or a 'test
>   source'?"

Gradle API tells IntelliJ which directories are marked as source and which are marked as test source.

Regarding your example:

1. All clear here, source and test source.
2. `awesome-test` source set defines `src/awesome-test/java` as source. Since test source path includes source path, no conflict here. And gradle/IntelliJ properly marking `src/awesome-test/java` as source.
3. `awesome-test` sourceset is added to test task, so clearly it is not being used as a source, hence marking it as test source.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Although I can use this to redesign my project structure to work with the new behavior introduced in 13.0.2 (13.0.1 seems to have taken what was in the idea config as truth), I would much rather be able to tell IntelliJ that "this" directory is a "test" directory. There are times when I need to define a source set that is used to set up a test, but does not get run as a test.

Comment: Do you have any links to documentation relating to this?

Comment: Are you trying to use some sort of a custom test framework, supporting your tests? If you can explain the context in better details, it might be helpful. Main documentations sources are [Gradle user guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) and StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes I am, and those supporting sources need to reference test sources. This causes issues because 'sources' cannot reference 'test sources'.

Comment: @MikeRylander Well, technically they can, but you will end up with a convoluted build file. Did you consider taking your test framework out into a separate module? We had the same situation in our company and moving it out worked just fine. Your test framework will become first class citizen, and can be referenced in tests as a dependency. Nice and clean.

Comment: We did consider it but ultimately decided it was not a good approach for this case (most of the framework is all ready separated). For now we have a work around until JetBrains fixes this in 13.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

In the past IntelliJ used the IdeaModel Configuration to set source and test directories. Based on an an [IntelliJ Ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120562) I opened, I believe that IntelliJ 13.1.0 will once again use the IdeaModel Configuration.